# Write into a database stored in App Group container from extension

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios-keyboard-extension, ios-app-group

I have a sqlite database stored in the App Group container in order to register custom shortcut.

I can read/write into it from the app, but not from the keyboard extension.
It seems that the database is in read-only mode from extensions.

I'm using the following code to access it:

```
let appGroupDirectoryPath = NSFileManager.defaultManager().containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier(appGroupId)
let dataBaseURL = appGroupDirectoryPath!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("database.sqlite")
```

Is there a workaround to be able to write into the database from the extension keyboard, or is it completely impossible?

The database is writable from the simulator but not with real devices. I guess it's because permissions are managed differently on MacOS X and iOS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out.

For keyboards, there is a property in the `Info.plist` file called **RequestsOpenAccess**. You can turn this on to *enable write access to the shared container*.

However, the end user will have to turn on "full access" in their settings for this keyboard, and they will be prompted with a scary message about how you could be logging their keystrokes.

Here's the Apple article that explains it:

[Designing for User Trust for Custom Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW2)